# How to fill object in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following object:

```
    FILES = (
        ('hello3.txt', True),

    )
```

How to add a new element to FILES?

I tried: `FILES.append("name.txt")`

I use this example and need to add to tuple all files from directory: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/QOMzUhZ2b3Q

Comment: Tuples are immutable, consider making `FILES` a list

Comment: Use `a = ['1', True]` and then `a.append('something')`

Comment: I use this example and need to add to tuple all files from directory: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/QOMzUhZ2b3Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'tuple' object does not support item assignment.`
and just like what Moses Koledoye says, tuple object is immutable.

If you want to add or remove to `FILES`,
try:

```
FILES = [('hello3.txt', True)]
FILES.append(('new.txt', False))
```

If you want to change the name of the file or the value of T/F, use `list` instead of `tuple`.

```
FILES = [['hello3.txt', True]]
FILES.append(['new.txt', False])
FILES[0][1] = False
```

But I think these codes are so ugly. I prefer to create a class instead of using the list.

```
class File:
    __slots__ = 'name', 'flag'
    def __init__(self, name, flag):
        self.name = name
        self.flag = flag
FILES = [File('hello3.txt', True)]
FILES.append(File('new.txt', False))
FILES[0].flag = False
```

There's also a simple way if your file only have 2 attributes (name and flag).

```
FILES = {'hello3.txt': True}
FILES['new.txt'] = False
```

Comment: @Griboedov Do you mean that you want to get all the files in the specific directory?

Answer (score 2):

You are using here tuples. There are immutable and you can't add something after they are created.

The best way is to use here an another data Structure: Lists!

```
FILES = ['hello3.txt', True]
```

now the append function can do its job

```
FILES.append("name.txt")
```

more about different data structures here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

If you need a more difficult and performant structure read about "Dictionaries".

Comment: So, is it right way? `FILES = []
        FILES.append((filename, True))`